# KDE Cantor with Anaconda

Tags: kde-plasma

I want to use KDE Cantor with python and packages from Anaconda.

I am running Linux Mint 20 XFCE, I have the cantor and cantor-backend-python3 packages installed, as well as miniconda.

Is there a way I can make Cantor use my conda environment, or import packages from conda in Cantor?

I am not sure what to change in the cantor python settings. I have also tried from the command line with the desired environment. If I run `python3` then `>>> import a_conda_package`, the package is imported. But `(base) $ cantor` then `import a_conda_package` is not found.

Thank you.